# How to add an Array of TextViews into a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, textview

I got this piece of code that creates new `TextView`, then adds it to `ArrayList<View>` and when it is finished adding `TextViews` to Array it sets adds that Array into `ListView`. But somehow my `ListView` is appearing empty. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ArrayList<View> textvs = new ArrayList<View>();
for (int i=0; i<10;i++) {
TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
tv.setText(""+i);
textvs.add(tv);
}
lv.addTouchables(portit); // lv is my listview
```

Comment: Is populating the list view what you wanna achieve ?

Comment: Read this post to understand the concept of listview http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Do you need to call setContentView()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ArrayAdapter`. You did this the wrong way. Here is a sample:

```
public class ArrayAdapterDemo extends ListActivity {
   String[] items = { "this", "is", "a", "really", "silly", "list" };
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
         android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
         items)); 
   }
```